# How to make the ReSharper extension work only on projects I selected

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2019, jetbrains-hub

ReSharper extension slows down the visual studio. It causes slowness in the projects I opened to look. How can i run only on projects i choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some projects to ReSharper | Options | Code Inspection | Ignored Code | Projects to ignore